# Can I add a title to an example using comment-based documentation?

Tags: powershell, documentation

For example, `Get-ChildItem` has this in its help:

```
-- Example 9: Output for experimental feature PSUnixFileStat --

    PS> Get-ChildItem /etc/r*
```

When I run `Get-Help` on my stuff, the bar just says `Example <number>`.

Writing the following:

```bsh
<#
.EXAMPLE Example title
example
#>
```

breaks `Get-Help`.

Do I need to use XML help or is there something else?

PS: The question submit form required me to not use "help" in the title. That's a bit silly in this case.

Comment: Thank you, schuelermine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to use XML help or is there something else?

Yes, **you do need to use *XML-based help in MAML format* if you want to customize your example-command section titles**. Authoring such help files is easiest via the **[`PlatyPS`](https://github.com/PowerShell/platyPS)** module, which enables writing your help in Markdown format (`*.md`) files that are compiled to MAML format.

**You cannot customize example-command section titles via *comment-based help*** (at least not as of PowerShell 7.2.x, but I suspect that won't change)  - see the [`.EXAMPLE` section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comment_Based_Help#example) documentation in the `about_Comment_Based_Help` conceptual help topic.

- The topic shows that only a select few sections accept arguments, and - as you've observed - trying to use an argument where none are supported breaks the comment-based help altogether.